# Put string in Handler

Tags: android, string, bundle, handler, msg

I've a little problem.I try to give a string to a handler.
I tried it with bundle.putString("key","String");  , but if i try to get the string, i got a nullpointerException. Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
 Message msg = new Message();
 Bundle b = new Bundle();

 b.putString("note","4.25");
 b.putString("fach", "Math");
 Log.d("DEBUG ",b.getString("note")+"  "+fach); //--> Here isn't a nullPointerException
 msg.setData(b);
 handler.sendMessage(msg);

 private Handler handler = new Handler() {

       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
Bundle b = msg.getData();
    Log.d("DEBUG,HANDLER","note "+b.getString("note")+" fach"+b.getString("fach")); //Throws 2 times null


}
}
```

Hope you can help me. Sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: Is b null, or are the keys null?

Comment: Thats a good question. The bundle is empty, when i get it.. (Bundle[{}]), 
But when i send it, it's full `(msg.getData().toString()= (Bundle[{note=4.25, fach=math})`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a lot of code to go on, but I would try using Message.obtain() instead of new Message(). I'm not convinced that the message you're receiving in handleMessage() is the one you sent in handler.sendMessage(). Both the sendMessage() and the handleMessage() have to be called on the same Thread, and you have to make sure you haven't put any other Message objects in the handler's MessageQueue.